# Substring problems

Tags: java, substring, charat

I'm trying to break up a string `192.168.1.2:6060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKNskFdtGO4"`.

I wanted to extract the `port:ip` before the first semicolon, and the branch number after the equal sign.

The code I tried was

```
temp = in.next();
System.out.println(temp.contains(";"));
System.out.println(temp.contains("="));
System.out.println("Temp: " + temp + " ");
sipName = temp.substring(0, temp.charAt(';'));
branch = temp.substring(temp.charAt('='));
```

I added the printlns to show if they characters were at least being found in the strings.

When I ran the code I get an StringIndexOutOfBoundsError at line `sipName = temp.substring(0, temp.charAt(';'));`

My console output is:

```
true
true
Temp: 192.168.1.2:6060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKb8NGxwdoR
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 59
...
```

It fails even if I just try `System.out.println(temp.charAt(';'));`

I'm not sure why this is happening. Is anyone able to explain? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `temp.indexOf(';')` instead of `temp.charAt(';')`.  Similarly, call `temp.indexOf('=')` instead of `temp.charAt('=')`.

`indexOf` tells you where the first occurrence of the given character is in the string.  `charAt` returns a character code rather than a position within the string, so it doesn't make sense where you use it.

(And at any rate, when you call `charAt` you pass in a position within the string and not a character code.  You could almost think of it as the opposite of `indexOf`.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it's been a while since I've had to use substring. Feel sort of silly now. I'll accept answer after the timer cool down.

Answer (score 1):

`String.charAt` takes an int. You are passing a char.
Refer here for reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29

Answer (score 1):

Replace chatAt with indexOf.

This charAt is a logical mistake, you actually wanted indexOf.

OK, others were faster ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
String sipName = StringUtils.substringBefore(str, ";");
String branch = StringUtils.substringAfter(str, "=");
```

[StringUtils docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is

```
temp.indexOf(";");
```

You don't get any exceptions at compile time because it converts the ";" into its ASCII value which is 59. So it tries to access the 60th element of this string. Finally, this gives you a

```
StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

at runtime.